# Python recv blocking before whole message is received

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I'm using Python socket to send protobuf serialized messages. 
The first message sent is the size of the next message.

**Client**

```
srz = msg.SerializeToString()
size = msg.ByteSize()
sock.sendall(bytes(str(size) + "\n", "utf-8"))
sock.sendall(srz)
```

**Server**

```
class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
def read_message(self,):
    self.data = self.rfile.readline().strip()

    try:
        msg_size = int(self.data)
    except ValueError:
        print('not a valid message size')
    print('expected message size', msg_size)
    received = 0
    message_s = bytes()
    while received != msg_size:
        message_s += self.request.recv(msg_size - received)
        received = len(message_s)
```

This seems to happen with messages bigger than 100KB. I debugged the code and the server blocks at the recv of the last packet.

Comment: Looks like you always request 8192 bytes, even when your message has fewer bytes than that left to read. You'll end up reading past the end of the message into the next message. Why not just use `self.rfile.read(msg_size)`?

Comment: 8192 is the maximum size I read everytime, it's not guaranteed that the exact number of specified bytes will be read.

Comment: I understand that, the point is that if you have more than 1 message you may end up reading past the end of your 1st message and into the 2nd message.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that code is wrong but it's not the cause of the problem. I think I have an idea of what's going on, I'll post updates

Comment: UPDATE:
I tried to put a sleep(1) before sending the serialized message to the server and it works, so for now what I'm doing is waiting for an answer from the server before sending the real message, it seems to work in this way.

Comment: Don't do that. Solve the problem. Sleeps don't solve anything, they just change the behaviour. You can't rely on it. You also need to solve the problem of over-reading. It could be causing this problem.

Comment: @EJP I fixed the over-reading (I updated the code), and I'm not using the sleep. I just changed the protocol so that there's always a reply before sending a new message. I wouldn't know how to solve it differently.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the [`socketserver`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html) module, but it seems you are using the underlying socket input stream in two different ways. In one way you're using it through `self.rflle` and in the other through `self.request`. The `rfile` attribute uses buffering and thus may read more than it returns, although I'm not completely certain. If so, you will not be able to mix the different ways to get data from the socket. Unread data will be sitting the `rfile` internal buffer forever.

Comment: @JamesKPolk that behavior would explain the problem, however I'm not sure how to prove it, I haven't found anything helpful in the docs.

Comment: You code is too incomplete to serve as an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so at this point there's nothing more to do.